# How can my NoSQL query be adapted to display the correct outcome? The expected outcome is to display the highest sales rank for Software

Tags: mysql, mongodb, nosql

I am following the method of (1) to find the highest sales rank of Software within a product as shown in (2) but it doesn't seem to be working. Within (3) it shows how I've tried to adapt it. Can anyone suggest why this isn't working?

(1) - The method I followed:

```
db.ads.find({Classification:"Clothes"}, {Manufacturer: 1, Model: 1, Price: 1})
      .sort({Price: -1})
      .limit(1)
```

(2) - The Fields of product
[image]

(3) - How I tried to adapt it but it isn't working:

```
db.my_products.find({mak_salesRank:"Software"}, {Software: 1})
              .sort({Software: -1})
              .limit(1)
```

Comment: Most people here want formatted text instead of images of text. (Can anyone read that tiny text?)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
db.my_products.find({}, {"mak_salesRank": 1})
          .sort({"mak_salesRank.Software": -1})
          .limit(1)
```

If this not correct, can you please show the expected result structure.

Comment: There are multiple software products with different values within the database, I'm trying to perform a query so it returns the highest value of software. Therefore I don't want to match the software within the query.

Comment: Can u just show an example for the BSON type of documents and expected result

Comment: {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5948e51f7efe5b9e060a71e7"),
    "mak_asin" : "1932703195",
    "mak_salesRank" : {
        "Software" : 29870
    },
    "mak_imUrl" : "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31vzKI9g3hL.jpg",
    "mak_description" : "medstudy pediatrics",
    "mak_categories" : [ 
        [ 
            "Musical Instruments", 
            "Instrument Accessories", 
            "General Accessories"
        ]
    ]
}

Comment: Answer Updated. Can you please check it with your expectation.


The things that I have understood from your comment is 

Just returns the highest value of software without matching with any field. Is it right ?

Comment: Yes that's correct, I just want to return the highest value of software without matching it to a specific field. How would I go about doing this? Thanks.

Comment: Answer is updated Yesterday (Before the comment). Can u try with this.